# How to connect to remotely SQL Server 2008 using MVC3 EF4

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4

I'm trying to connect remotely and I have the following connection string on my MVC3 using EF4 ctp5 code first

```
<add name="ApplicationServicesX"
     connectionString="provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string='Data Source=asc-svr2;
     Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks;Integrated Security=True;Connection Timeout=60;
     multipleactiveresultsets=true'" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

and it gives an error

```
[ProviderIncompatibleException: The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string.]
```

and

```
Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication.
```

my controller looks like this

```
 public ActionResult Index()
 {
     var post = cmsDB.Posts.ToList();
             return View(post);
}
```

When I run the code on my local machine no problem at all but when I get into 
remotely connecting into SQL Server 2008 the problem arises.

Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: Does the remote SQL server allow connections from other servers? Named Pipes or by TCP/IP ?

Answer (score 1):

Your connection string is configured to use Integrated Windows Authentication (`Integrated Security=True`). For this to work make sure you have enabled NTLM in IIS. Also if the SQL Server is on a different physical machine than the web server you might need to [configure delegation](http://wiki.asp.net/page.aspx/44/impersonation-and-delegation/). As an alternative you could use SQL authentication with a fixed account:

```
<add name="ApplicationServicesX"
     connectionString="provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string='Data Source=asc-svr2; Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks;User Id=foo;Password=secret;Connection Timeout=60;multipleactiveresultsets=true'" 
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Comment: thanks @darin i saw the problem the SSPI windows authentication should be removed on the connection string

Comment: I've tried this solution but i still get the same error. What can i be doing wrong?